# How to make this php page load faster

Tags: php, api, pageload, page-load-time

I am working on a php page that basically connects to Harvest using the Harvest API and fetches some Information. The code basically returns all the user objects in Harvest and calculates the expenses for each user. It takes around 50 seconds to load. Please see my code below-

```
<?php require_once( 'connection.php' );
  $result= $api->getUsers();
  $users=$result->data;



  $range= Harvest_Range::lastMonth();


  foreach($users as $key=>$value){

 $user_id=$value->get("id");
 $first_name=$value->get("first-name");
 $last_name=$value->get('last-name'); 

  $result_expenses=$api->getUserExpenses($user_id, $range);
 $expenses_data=$result_expenses->data;

 $total_cost=0;

foreach($expenses_data as $key=>$value){
if($value->get("is-locked")=="true"){
$total_cost=$total_cost+$value->get("total-cost");

}} 
 ?>
 <?php if($total_cost!=0){?>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td> <?php echo $first_name; echo " ".$last_name; ?> </td>
 <td> $ <?php echo $total_cost; ?> </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <?php }}?>

 </table>
```

Is there any way to make the page load faster?

Comment: start by benchmarking it and finding what are the slow parts.

Comment: I think you have to cache that records first on your side and after that you can take the data from your cache or local database

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to make those kinds of requests at runtime when a user requests a page. You should do as @OsDev suggests. Have a background script that does the call and calculations at a set interval and store the results in some cache (memcache, redis or similar) or in some database. Then the visitors only need to fetch the data from the cache or database.

Comment: The reason seems to be you're doing one request per user. This will definitely kill performance. Does Harvest supply an endpoint where you can get expenses for N users at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is slow because you are requesting data for each user, one at a time. This means that as you get more users you are going to have to make more requests. More requests means your application will take longer and longer.

Unfortunately it appears you are only able to request data from one user at a time: http://mdbitz.com/docs/harvest-api/

If you are able to store the data locally you could greatly increase the speed of your application. You can store it anywhere that is easily accessible such as a database, cache or even a text file. Then you will need to determine how often you update your local copy from the Harvest API to get the latest data.